# Patchwork legend collecting fails

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have been trying to collect legends of plots created in a loop. However, this fails to produce the desired result, as the legends are not collected. I tried

```
(res[[1]] / res[[2]]) + plot_layout(guides = "collect") + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

where `res[[1]]` and `res[[2]]` are list elements created in the loop.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mikj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `+ theme(legend.position = "bottom")`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl, color = as.factor(vs))) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl, color = as.factor(vs))) +
  geom_point()

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

Or if you'd like to place the legend in the center:

```
p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Comment: Awesome that was exactly what I needed. Thank you for that :)